# difference between nnet and train(model,method=nnet

Tags: r

What is the difference between these `two R commands`?

```
mymodel <- train(y~., data =da,method = "nnet",linout = TRUE)
```

and

```
mymodel=nnet(y~.,data=da,size=1)
```

Comment: I presume the two here come from different packages-- `train()` from `caret` package can take many different machine learning  methods , of which neural net is one. See here http://topepo.github.io/caret/bytag.html. On the other hand nnet trains a neural net. You can also use `names(caret::getModelInfo())` to see what methods are supported by caret

Comment: the `caret` package wraps and provide a consistent interface to a plethora of algorithms. There is no difference between those two statements except that `caret` ends up executing the model code vs you executing it directly.

Comment: when I excuted both of them train() command take much more time than nnet() why ?